# Python delete a row that meets a condition

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to translate this matlab sentence to python in a efficient way

```
Matlab: pairs(sum(pairs, 2) == 0, :) = [];
```

pairs is a [N,2] matrix where matrix for instance it can be 30

Exists any similar syntax in python like [] in order to delete the row that meets the condition sum(pairs, 2) == 0?

Comment: could you explain what research have you completed so far before you posted the question?

Comment: Use [`delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) plus [`where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Answer (score 3):

Numpy provides the `where` function:

```
import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.where(x <= 2)
(array([0, 1], dtype=int64),)
```

or

```
>>> x = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
>>> x
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

>>> x[np.where( x < 5 )]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

using `where` and `delete` in combination, you can for example delete the first row in the above matrix using this:

```
>>> np.delete(x, np.where(np.all(x < 3,axis=1)), axis=0)
array([[3, 4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without numpy as well.

```
vec = [1, 2, 3, 4]
vec = [x for x in vec if x <=2]
vec
[1, 2]
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions